# Difference between NG_VALIDATORS and validators (Class)

Tags: angular

I'm confused on what's the usage of NG_VALIDATORS, I know it is a provider token. But what's its use? How is it any different form validators class?

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.3.3/packages/forms/src/validators.ts

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have two ways to add validators to a form control. Using imperative approach by specifying them as a parameter to a form control:

```
const ctrl = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
```

or declaratively by using validator specific directives in the template:

```
<input [formControl]='ctrl' required>
```

The `NG_VALIDATORS` token is used in the second case. These tokens are defined by the validators directives `required`, `email` an others. And they are defined on the injector created by form directives - `NgForm`, `NgModel` and `NgModelGroup`. See [How exactly works the services hierarchy in this Angular 2 application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45549137/how-exactly-works-the-services-hierarchy-in-this-angular-2-application/45549301#45549301) to learn  more about directives creating its own injector.

All built-in and custom validators are registered using this token:

```
export const EMAIL_VALIDATOR: any = {
  provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => EmailValidator),
  multi: true
};
@Directive({
  selector: '[email]...',
  providers: [EMAIL_VALIDATOR]  <-------------
})
export class EmailValidator implements Validator {
```

---

```
export const REQUIRED_VALIDATOR: Provider = {
  provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => RequiredValidator),
  multi: true
};
@Directive({
  selector:
      '[required]...',
  providers: [REQUIRED_VALIDATOR],  <-------------
})
export class RequiredValidator implements Validator {
```

---

Angular reactive and template driven form directives (`NgForm`, `NgModel` and `NgModelGroup`) inject validators using this token:

```
export class NgForm extends ControlContainer implements Form {
  ...    
  constructor(
      @Optional() @Self() @Inject(NG_VALIDATORS) validators: any[],
```

---

```
export class NgModel extends NgControl implements OnChanges,
  ...
  constructor(@Optional() @Self() @Inject(NG_VALIDATORS) validators...,
```

---

```
export class NgModelGroup extends AbstractFormGroupDirective implements ... {
  ...
  constructor(
      @Optional() @Self() @Inject(NG_VALIDATORS) validators: any[],
```

The same goes for the `NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS` token.

Comment: Thanks for you reply! It's very helpful, but i have a doubt....For reactive forms, why do we import the validators class. I know it has those validator methods. If NG_VALIDATORS already have those validators registered, why have two things that look like to be doing the same thing (not sure if i'm right) ?

Comment: You can add validators declaratively using directives - `required`, `email` and others or imperatively by importing and adding them into `new FormControl()`. I'll add this information to the answer

Comment: Ok so i just look at the background of NG_VALIDATORS which is an instance of InjectionToken which is basically a class. So when i use NG_VALIDATORS (which is a class) in the provide (of a provider) and use "useExisting: forwardRef(() => EmailValidator)," where EmailValidator is again a class. Now the question, how do those two classes NG_VALIDATORS and EmailValidators link with each other or individually in a provider?

Comment: I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45560676/2545680) in your other question. Is there anything else unclear about my **this** answer?