# How does these angular email directive code snippets connect

Tags: angular

So i was looking at the angular core files, I'm a bit confused on how these four pieces of code connect?

1. Code for injection token which is a class

```
    export class InjectionToken extends OpaqueToken {
          private _differentiate_from_OpaqueToken_structurally: any;
          constructor(desc: string) { super(desc); }

          toString(): string { return `InjectionToken ${this._desc}`; }
    }
```

2. Code for NG_VALIDATORS which uses the injection token

```
    export const NG_VALIDATORS = new InjectionToken>('NgValidators');
```

3. Required validator which uses the NG_VALIDATORS

```
    export const REQUIRED_VALIDATOR: Provider = {   
        provide: NG_VALIDATORS,   
        useExisting: forwardRef(() => RequiredValidator),   
        multi: true 
    };
```

```
    @Directive({
        ...
    }) export class RequiredValidator implements Validator {
        //Code here
    }
```

I am having problem tracing back the code from the declaration of REQUIRED_VALIDATOR to injection token. I understand about most of the basic elements but not sure how the "useExisting" is being used for RequiredValidator class (i understand forwardRef). And how NG_VALIDATORS gets benefited, which itself being a constant by definition

Comment: dependency injection is one key concept of Angular, see [this documentation](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection). Even as it is almost easy to use, the code behind it is quite complex .

Comment: hey, did [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45560676/2545680) help you?

Comment: I'm still confused on the fact regarding NG_VALIDATORS, as i was reading on multi providers https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular2/2015/11/23/multi-providers-in-angular-2.html

It talks about NG_VALIDATORS being a container for all built in validators plus any custom ones we declare. Your answer talks about  redirection of request from one token to another. Although i understand the core concept but i'm just researching on the core angular code for how NG_VALIDATORS gets initialized and attached on the form itself

Comment: okay, take your time. the articles on thoughtram are not very deep, they often represent the internals in the overly simplistic way. _NG_VALIDATORS being a container for all built in validators_ - this is not true because otherwise you would have all validators added elsewhere for the input on particular form

Comment: I'm not sure but if i have the concept up at graps, but please excuse if i misused the word container that's what i'm linking to, although which might be wrong

Comment: Not sure if container is the right word, but more like array. Just looked at the angular docs which says about multi providers as "Note the multi: true option. This is required and tells Angular that HTTP_INTERCEPTORS is an array of values, rather than a single value" on https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-all-requests-or-responses

Answer (score 4):

In Angular DI system a token can be any reference **available in runtime** including an instance of a class. So here you have an instance of a class `InjectionToken`:

```
export const NG_VALIDATORS = new InjectionToken>('NgValidators');
```

referenced by the variable `NG_VALIDATORS`.

Angular DI system introduces a strategy that can redirect the request from one token to another. And this is the strategy that is used here:

```
export const REQUIRED_VALIDATOR: Provider = {   
    provide: NG_VALIDATORS,   
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => RequiredValidator),   
    multi: true 
};
```

But what does it redirect to? It redirects to the token referenced by the class `RequiredValidator`. To understand where `RequiredValidator` comes from you need to know that Angular adds directive class instances to the element injector. So if you have two directives:

```
@Directive({selector:'adir'...}) export class ADirective {}
@Directive({selector:'bdir'...}) export class BDirective {}
```

And apply them like this:

```
<input adir bdir>
```

The injector created on these elements will contain the following providers:

```
[
  { token: ADirective, instance: new ADirective() },
  { token: BDirective, instance: new BDirective() }
]
```

And so any directive that is added to this element will be able to inject these instances by the class token.

So in the case of `required` validator when you apply a directive `required` to an element:

```
<input required>
```

in the injector the instance of the `RequiredValidator` is created by the token `RequiredValidator` and this is exactly the token to which `NG_VALIDATORS` redirects.